# CSS and jQuery to make a slide panel, that push the other div horizontal, and not down, and the right panel has to fill all the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have two `div` elements, one is the left panel, that is hidden, and collapse/expand accordingly it's needed. In the right I have another `div` that has to be pushed containing an `iframe`, this `iframe` hast to fill all the screen or remaining of the screen. Right now the left  div is pushing my right div down.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddre54/cZjMR/3/) is the code that I have, the red border represents my left panel (collapse/expand). And the one with the `iframe` represents the right.

Can you help me please, so the left panel pushes the other panel horizontally and the right panel adjust to fit the window accordingly.

Comment: You should take a look at this answer : [horizontal page sliding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414642/responsive-horizontal-page-sliding-navigation/24465646#24465646)

Comment: @web-tiki Hi, thanks for the example on a different approach for the solution, but actually the answer given by **eteich** solved my problem. It's exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I don't think widow width dependent scripts are the best to fiddle out.

Second, avoid CSS height:100% like the plague... it doesn't work well, you could pass window.height() into a variable and set them with jQuery.

Third, you might want to target the iframe as well as the outer div.

http://jsfiddle.net/eteich/cZjMR/8/

Comment: Thanks @eteich, that  it's what I wanted, I think I will follow your advise with the height as well. If you have an advise to where to set the height, or should I add a listener for rezise to set it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eteich/cZjMR/12/

Just set the height like you did the margin in the beginning.